# Will a factory reset wipe the apps that i have installed?

Tags: factory-reset

If I factory reset my device will it wipe all my apps and music like Clash of Clans? I want to know before I do this to my device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you factory reset your phone it will wipe everything that is on your phone.  You can get all your apps back once you factory reset it, and as long as they are linked to certain accounts, the progress will still be there.  You can back up your music, pictures, and contacts to your google account so all will be restored once you reset your phone, and log back in with your google account.

Answer (score 1):

`If I factory reset my device will wipe all my apps and music like clash of clans?` **-- Yes.**
A factory reset results in a full reset of an Android device to the original settings of the currently-installed ROM.

What is the **purpose** of factory-reset?
This is often done to fix a software issue that the device is facing, but it could also be done to restore the device to its original settings

Also, mostly, `Data on the SIM card and the MicroSD card are not erased.`

**Quotes** from [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset)

What a factory reset does is basically to "wipe" (delete all content) from the **/cache** (holding the application cache) and **/data** (user data and user-installed apps, dalvik cache) partitions. Other media, like internal-sd and external-sd cards, are usually left untouched

Refer [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you will lose all data in your device. Be sure to backup everything before resetting device.

Comment: Everything stored at the external SD card won't be touched by the Factory reset.

Comment: Yeah, users will be prompted to remove/unmount the card. I was talking about the apps and internal memory in general :)